# rails 5 api returns 301 from PORO

Tags: json, api, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 5.0.0.1 API application that needs to return a simple PORO as json.  I am using gem 'responders', '~> 2.3.0'

The object constructs correctly and works properly in the Rails server.  It has only 4 attributes that are needed by the front-end.

The serializer is:

```
class WebsiteConfigSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes  :force_first_user_to_be_admin,   :allows_delete_of_last_admin,
              :is_private_website,            :invite_only
end
```

The controller show method (the only method in the controller) is:

```
def show
  config = WebsiteConfig.new
  puts "Config:  #{config.to_json}"
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render( json: config, status: 200 )  }
  end
end
```

The log shows the request output, including the debugging puts statement:

```
Started GET "/config.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-09-03 18:23:32 -0400
Processing by WebsiteConfigController#show as JSON
Config: {"force_first_user_to_be_admin":true, "allows_delete_of_last_admin":false, "is_private_website":true, "invite_only":true}
[active_model_serializers] Rendered WebsiteConfigSerializer with ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::Attributes (0.13ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

as expected.

The output of cURL is:

```
curl -sb -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:3000/config
<html>
  <head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
  <body bgcolor="white">
    <center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
    <hr><center>nginx</center>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is NOT what I expected.

wget output is EMPTY (0 bytes).  Also not what I expected.

Obviously I am missing something.  Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your request has been redirected, check if you have some authentication code like requiring login or something else, then added them to the curl command